# How to make an animation in React?

Tags: reactjs, animation, slide, effect

I'm trying to figure out how to add an animation on the next elements. I was trying some stuff but didn't figure it out due the fact that I recently started to learn React.

```html
<div className="gradient2">
   <div className="grid grid-rows-3 stoljpi-metci grid-flow-col">
      <div className="font-bold text-white pl-1.5 bojaTexta">&nbsp;{metciTren}</div>
      <div className="font-bold text-gray-400 -mt-1">&nbsp;{clipMetci}</div>
   </div>
   <>
--Anim should go here, I want the className='slikea' to be animated, like slideIn 
   <div className='slikea'>
      <img className="stoljpi mt-1" src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/${state}.png`} />
   </div>
   </>
</div>
```

Comment: try https://react-spring.dev/, it has a lot of APIs for you to animated your app